# import error in django-sendsms

Tags: django

I'm trying to use `django-sendsms` based on [this documentation](https://github.com/stefanfoulis/django-sendsms)

I downloaded the package,copied it's folder in `c:` and ran this command in shell

```
c:
cd django-sendsms
python setup.py install
```

these commands installed django-sms in sitepackages folder.then based on the documentation I added this backend to `settings.py`:

```
SENDSMS_BACKEND = 'sendsms.backends.console.SmsBackend'
```

and in `views.py` :

```
from sendsms import api
api.send_sms(body='I can haz txt', from_phone='+41791111111', to=['+41791234567'])
```

but I get this error:

```
No module named importlib
```

every thing is based on the documentation,I don't know what's wrong with it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of Python are you using? It seems that module (in sendsms/util.py) will import the library called importlib which only exists in Python 2.7. If you are using Python 2.6 or lower, that library do not exist.

Comment: python 2.6 ,what should I do know?

Comment: There are several backports of importlib to 2.x, you can find them on http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3Aaction=search&term=importlib&submit=search. I think you may try to install one of them to see if it works or not.